# Tomcat Server Standalone Exe

Tags: java, tomcat

Is it possible to run a java servlet via tomcat in a local standalone app?

App/Plugin -- JSON (POST/GET) -- Local Tomcat exe with java servlet

Answer (score 1):

I think your question has been address here:

[Java web application in a Servlet container vs. standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589307/java-web-application-in-a-servlet-container-vs-standalone)

what you want is a stand alone servlet